# R: aggregate data rows with same date and attributes into a weekly counts for time series

Tags: r, count, statistics, aggregate, time-series

I have the following data that I put together in Excel by combining weekly reports completed on fridays in the last year. Each row is an open account.

```
location code  days.open     report.date 
LA       C1    186          8/2/2013    
SF       C2    186          8/2/2013    
SF       M     18           8/2/2013    
LA       C1    130          7/26/2013    
HB       M     30           7/26/2013    
LA       F     2            7/19/2013    
HB       F     188          7/19/2013    
LA       C3    90           7/12/2013    
LB       F     30           7/12/2013    
LB       F     36           7/12/2013    
SF       M     94           7/12/2013    
NB       C1    6            7/5/2013    
HB       M     18           7/5/2013    
LB       M     35           6/28/2013    
SD       C3    201          6/28/2013    
SD       F     69           6/21/2013
```

and so for over a million entries.

This is my first time using R for timeseries and I need help preparing the data for time series analysis.

I have a few things I want to look at:
1) the count of open accounts at each report date
2) the count of open accounts at each report date by location
3) the coount of open accounts at each report date by code
4) the count of open accounts seperated into days.open<=30 , 30 < days.open <= 60, 60 < days.open <= 90, days open > 90
5) The same counts as #4 further broken down by location.

I am not quite sure where to start.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Posing a project and then saying "don't know where to start" really means: Read the "Introduction to R". This is not a tutorial site. You need to do some work on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert data into its format and use `plyr` package or `data.table` package. The following is the solution using `ddply` from plyr package. You should read [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CD4QFjAD&url=http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper&ei=S5IOUt7UMeSb2QXhiYC4Bw&usg=AFQjCNH3rcSknA7oCUQvDKqs7sdmpF1gMg&bvm=bv.50768961,d.b2I) article if you want to use plyr. In the following code, mydata is your data.

```
mydata$report.date<-as.Date(mydata$report.date,"%m/%d/%Y")

library(plyr)
ddply(mydata,.(report.date),summarize, freq=length(days.open)) #1
ddply(mydata,.(report.date,location),summarize, freq=length(days.open)) #2
ddply(mydata,.(report.date,code),summarize, freq=length(days.open)) #3
```

Generate a variable that assigns days.open into four intervals.

```
mydata$new<-with(mydata,ifelse(days.open<=30,"A",ifelse(days.open>30 & days.open<=60,"B",ifelse(days.open>60 & days.open<=90,"C","D"))))

ddply(mydata,.(new),summarize, freq=length(days.open)) #4
ddply(mydata,.(new,location),summarize, freq=length(days.open)) #5
```

**output for last one**

```
   new location freq
1    A       HB    2
2    A       LA    1
3    A       LB    1
4    A       NB    1
5    A       SF    1
6    B       LB    2
7    C       LA    1
8    C       SD    1
9    D       HB    1
10   D       LA    2
11   D       SD    1
12   D       SF    2
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was not quite sure what package to start with. I read the documentation for several packages that seemed to have the funcitons I needed for my purposes. Thanks to you Plyr will be my go to for prepping timeseries data for the forecast package.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer to your last question - once you understand this, the rest will be trivial:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(your_df)

cuts = c(-Inf, 30, 60, 90, Inf)
dt[, .N, by = list(cut(days.open, cuts), location)]
#          cut location N
# 1: (90, Inf]       LA 2
# 2: (90, Inf]       SF 2
# 3: (-Inf,30]       SF 1
# 4: (-Inf,30]       HB 2
# 5: (-Inf,30]       LA 1
# 6: (90, Inf]       HB 1
# 7:   (60,90]       LA 1
# 8: (-Inf,30]       LB 1
# 9:   (30,60]       LB 2
#10: (-Inf,30]       NB 1
#11: (90, Inf]       SD 1
#12:   (60,90]       SD 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This will be helpful in the future.